# Cute Editor: Javascript input

Tags: asp.net, cuteeditor

Who has expirience with [Cute Editor](http://www.richtextbox.com/cs/default.aspx) - does it validate javascript input or not?
What settings must be applyed?Must I write my own filter for this goals?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "validate"? CuteEditor can remove scripts from content - is that it? If you really mean validate javascript then I suggest you take a look at [jslint](http://www.jslint.com).